The USB mouse is not working after Debian 11 system startup. I gave up
Reconnecting the mouse solves the issue but it's not a solution in the long run. I haven't found the solution that would work for me. Maybe the answer to this question will be a reference to everyone who came across similar problem. I've tried almost everything what can be found on the Internet and what can be done in a reasonable time. I have the same problem every few years with subsequent installations of Debian-like systems. I once had a similar problem on Ubuntu, I don't remember how I fixed it. This time Debian 11. I am on a desktop computer.
On system boot I get:
[    3.088867] usb 9-4: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[    3.260869] usb 9-4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.536877] usb 9-4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.804858] usb 9-4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[    4.000891] usb 9-4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    4.328872] usb 9-4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    4.632868] usb 9-4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[    5.048882] usb 9-4: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[    5.232845] usb 9-4: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[    5.648874] usb 9-4: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[    5.648930] usb usb9-port4: unable to enumerate USB device


After reconnecting the mouse:
[  409.323933] usb 9-4: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
[  409.519042] usb 9-4: New USB device found, idVendor=15ca, idProduct=00c3, bcdDevice= 5.12
[  409.519051] usb 9-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  409.519056] usb 9-4: Product: USB Optical Mouse


I have tampered with options like:
1.
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
usbcore.old_scheme_first=1


in /etc/default/grub, doing update-grub and rebooting the system

Powering on and off certain usb ports:

# disable autosuspend of the USB device
echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/9-4/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
# powering off the usb port
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/9-4/power/control"
# after boot the mouse if off so turn the device on
echo "on" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/9-4/power/control"


If the device was not detected, its USB port does not even exist in the system, it cannot be turned on/off. This option of turning off and turning on the USB port works only after reconnecting the mouse after system startup, and yes, it works then, but how to turn it on before reconnecting the mouse?

Powering on and off whole USB controllers on PCI bus, first trying of course which is responsible for a given USB port:

echo -n "0000:00:13.2" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:13.2" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind


but without harming the system of course.
None of the above helped.

https://forum.zorin.com/t/usb-descriptor-read-64-error-32/4718/4   https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiSIEM/Technical-Tip-Device-descriptor-read-64-error-and-unable-to/ta-p/195196   So, it all points out to power issues of the USB port or (internal) hub controller that, in your case, happen in a cold boot. An UEFI update may or may not have solved it already.

Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it. I have already visited the given link. I will check the UEFI update option and I will give some feedback.
